# Delete a specific child on multiple parent node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an app where when the user delete his/her account all his data record in the database will also be deleted (ex. in friends, the nodes that are equal to his uid will also be deleted automatically unfriending the other user/s.

[image: this is the database structure]

Comment: You should write a firebase function to delete all the posts made by the user.

Answer (score 1):

i am removing a friend from my friend list :-

```
private void removeFromFriend(final String type, String id) {

        Map hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put(firebaseUser.getUid() + "/" + id, null);
        hashMap.put(id + "/" + firebaseUser.getUid(), null);

        mDatabaseReference.child(userFriendListTableName).updateChildren(hashMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                if (databaseError == null) {
                    profileDialog.dismiss();
                    friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("block")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Blocked Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (type.equals("report")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Report as spam successfully and removed from friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User removed from friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

do this way if you want to update 2 or many table in one reference :-

```
friendsMap.put(userFriendListTableName + "/" + currentUserId + "/" + userId + "/friend_id", userId);
                friendsMap.put(userFriendListTableName + "/" + currentUserId + "/" + userId + "/acceptDate", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                friendsMap.put(userFriendListTableName + "/" + userId + "/" + currentUserId + "/friend_id", currentUserId);
                friendsMap.put(userFriendListTableName + "/" + userId + "/" + currentUserId + "/acceptDate", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                friendsMap.put(friendRequestTableName + "/" + currentUserId + "/" + userId, null);
                friendsMap.put(friendRequestTableName + "/" + userId + "/" + currentUserId, null);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(friendsMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                        if (databaseError != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

in this i am removing the both user from friend request list and add both the users in friend list

Comment: I made a mistake on the title I edited it now. It should be deleted on multiple parent (if he has more than one) but thanks for your answer. Im still seeking the correct function

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference friendsRef = rootRef.child("Friends");
DatabaseReference uidRef = friendsRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if(ds.child(uid).exists()) {
                            ds.child(uid).getRef().removeValue();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                }
            };
            friendsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

This code does the followings, first it checks if the uid of the user exists, if it doesn't  it means that the user has deleted the account. This is also means that you need to take action by querying the database to find all the users that have a child equal to that particular uid. This is a solution that works client side.

However, if you want to do it automatically, then you should write a function, in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which will help you run backend code in response to events that happen in your database.

Comment: I solved the issue. Sadly not this answer but thanks anyway

Comment: Have you even tried my soluton?

Comment: yes but your answer is helpful

Comment: Please add the as an answer the way you have solved the problem. In whis way you can also help future users.